# Running a machine code program on Vice Emulator (Vic-20)

Tags: emulation

Does anyone know how to get a machine code program running on the Vice Vic-20 emulator? I keep getting the the emulator doing a reset every time i try it.

If i use the following code it should print an "A" on the screen but i don't see anything. Program is loaded at memory location $1001 for an unexpanded Vic-20

LDA #$01

STA $1E00

RTS

Thanks

Allan

Comment: Isn't A 65 in ASCII, = 41 hex not 01?

Comment: Yes it is. But 01 is the value to print a capital 'A" to the video memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to end with BRK and not RTS. How are you calling the code? SYS 4097 I assume. The BRK should force you back to the prompt. RTS is looking for return address on stack and there isn't one it's not the right one.